# Tag synonyms: [gnome-shell-extension] and [gnome-extensions]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

I just found out there's a [gnome-extensions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gnome-extensions) tag.

I think it's just a synonym of the older and well-documented [gnome-shell-extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gnome-shell-extension) tag. So [gnome-extensions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gnome-extensions) should be merged with [gnome-shell-extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gnome-shell-extension).

I have suggested a [tag synonym](https://askubuntu.com/tags/gnome-shell-extension/synonyms).